# AWS Kinesis Firehose - using Index Rotation (Elasticsearch)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have set up a new `AWS Kinesis Firehose` stream and I'd like to create a new index on a weekly basis.

For that, I should use `Index Rotation` setting when configuring the stream.

But, do I have to the new index every weekend for the next upcoming week?
If not (hopefully not), how does `Firehose` knows what mapping to use? does it use the mapping defined in the index that I specified in the `Index` setting?

More over, lets say I have old data, can I make `Firehose` to create an index with the relevant timestamp according to the dates in specified in my old data?

Thank you !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, apparently the answer is yes, **but in a bad way.**

If `Firehose` pushes data to a new index, that is not pre-defined with a mapping, that data is ingested to `Elasticsearch` and a mapping is created automatically for you.

This is really bad.

You should auto create an index 1-2 hours prior the event.
I'll post a `Lambda` function and its configuration for doing that automatically.

Comment: You can use elasticsearch index templates, to store your mappings. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Comment: I know this is old, but this shouldn't be the accepted answer. Index templates is the correct way to achieve what OP asked for.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to consider creating index template in elastic search. Thay way new indexes will pick the mapping defined in index template.

Refer to following link for details

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html